# Calling R.net using SQLCLR function

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclr, r.net

I have written a CLR function that interacts with R.net and executes the test.R file. This function is working perfectly fine when I ran it from C#.net application. I then built a dll for this application and integrated it with Sql server 2012. When I try to call this method from sql server It keep executing the command and nothing happens. Can you please suggest me whats might have gone wrong? 
Following is snippet of my code
C#:

```cs
 public static void  callfrmFile(out string result)
    {

        try
        {
            REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables();
            REngine engine = REngine.GetInstance();
            engine.Initialize();
            engine.Evaluate("setwd('E://Clients//RStuido')");
            engine.Evaluate("source('test1.R')");
            engine.Dispose();
            result = "1";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = ex.Message;
        }     
    }
```

SQL Server:

```sql
CREATE PROC spa_callRfrmFile
(@result NVARCHAR(1024) OUTPUT)
AS
    EXTERNAL NAME Rintegrate.[Rintegrate.UDF].callfrmFile
GO

DECLARE @a NVARCHAR(500)
EXEC spa_callRFrmFile @a OUT
SELECT @a
```

Comment: IIRC, there's a switch in SQL to enable CLR, and by default it's set to false. Have you checked that?

Comment: CLR Is enabled. I can run other functions from same clr. I am just not being able to access this particular one.

Comment: Have you loaded the Assembly containing the `REngine` class into SQL Server? You are not getting any error at all?

Comment: I have loaded RDotNet.NativeLibrary and Rdotnet.dll assemblies to SQL server. I think these assemblies contain REngine. And no I do not get any error.  store procedure keeps executing infinitely

Comment: What `PERMISSION_SET` is each Assembly? Also, "never returning" is vastly different than "returning nothing". How long have you allowed for a timeout?

Comment: Both have UNSAFE Permission_set and time out is set for 600s. But I do not get any error related with timeout.

Comment: What is the `PERMISSION_SET` of your Assembly?  600 seconds is 10 minutes. How long have you let it run for? Also, what is the service account for the MSSQLSERVER (or whatever the instance name is) process? Is it Local System? If Local System, that might be a problem. I don't know about R permissions, but the process will connect to R using the service account since you aren't using Impersonation.

Comment: I somehow was able to get following error 'Error in library(neuralnet) : there is no package called 'neuralnet'', where neuralnet is a r external library. I tried to create an assembly of this package but it wasn't compatible with the sql server. Do you guys have any suggestion on how I can refer external library of R?